# Hide Tab Bar from Stack Navigator Without tabBarVisible option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I found some answers with **old** versions of navigation, with **"tabBarVisible"** option in Tab Navigator.
But since there is no more this option I want to know how to hide Tab Bar in specific screens INSIDE Stack Navigators
This is my Tab Navigator:

```
<Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName='Passports'
            screenOptions={{
                "tabBarLabelStyle": {
                    "fontSize": 12
                },
                "tabBarStyle": {
                    "backgroundColor": "white"
                }
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name='EquipmentStack'
                component={EquipmentStack}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel:'Equipment'
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name='ObjectsStack'
                component={ObjectsStack}
                options={{ tabBarLabel:'Objects'}}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name='DocumentationStack'
                component={DocumentationStack}
                options={{ tabBarLabel:'Documentation'}}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
```

And my First Stack navigator:

```
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Equipment'
                component={Equipment}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
           />
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Equipment Details'
                component={EquipmentDetails}
                options={{title:'Equipment Details'}}/>
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Equipment Details Update'
                component={EquipmentDetailsUpdate}
                options={{title:'Equipment Details Update'}}/>
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Equipment Details Update Zander'
                component={EquipmentDetailsUpdateZander}
                options={{title:'Equipment Details Update Zander'}}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

I want to hide Tab Bar only in 3 screens out of 4 in my stack:
"Equipment"                       1 Screen : Tab Bar
"Equipment Details"               2 Screen : No Tab Bar
"Equipment Details Update"        3 Screen : No Tab Bar
"Equipment Details Update Zander" 4 Screen : No Tab Bar

Also My 2 other Stack Navigator are same, and i also want to do same thing to them :

```
<Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Objects'
                component={Objects}
                options={{headerShown: false}}/>
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Objects Details'
                component={ObjectsDetails}/>
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Objects Details Update'
                component={ObjectsDetailsUpdate}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

```
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Documentation'
                component={Documentation}
                options={{headerShown: false}}/>
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Documentation Details'
                component={DocumentationDetails}/>
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Documentation Details Update'
                component={DocumentationDetailsUpdate}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding what you are trying to achieve can be done as below. can you check

```
export const TabNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Passports"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          fontSize: 12,
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        },
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Equipment"
        component={Equipment}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Equipment',
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Objects"
        component={Objects}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Objects',
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Documentation"
        component={Documentation}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Equipment',
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export const StackNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="TabNavigation"
        component={TabNavigation}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Equipment Details"
        component={EquipmentDetails}
        options={{title: 'Equipment Details'}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Equipment Details Update"
        component={EquipmentDetailsUpdate}
        options={{title: 'Equipment Details Update'}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Equipment Details Update Zander"
        component={EquipmentDetailsUpdateZander}
        options={{title: 'Equipment Details Update Zander'}}
      />

      <Stack.Screen name="Objects Details" component={ObjectsDetails} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Objects Details Update"
        component={ObjectsDetailsUpdate}
      />

      <Stack.Screen
        name="Documentation Details"
        component={DocumentationDetails}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Documentation Details Update"
        component={DocumentationDetailsUpdate}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For the current version (v6.x) you can use: tabBarStyle option passing display as none:

```
    tabBarStyle: {
        display: 'none'
    }
```

and if you wish to show the tabBar again, just the the display to flex (default value).